# Web API On IIS 10 (Handler "ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler")

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I built a basic RESTful web service so that I can receive events. I can run this fine on local IIS, but have the following error when publishing it in IIS 10 on a server

> HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error
>   Handler "ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler"

I set the application pool Managed Pipeline Mode to Integrated and enabled Directory Browsing in the app features. My web config looks like this:

```
<system.webServer>
<modules>
  <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
</modules>
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

If I change the application pool Managed Pipeline Mode to "Classic" I can actually see the root site but trying to browse or call to the API gives 404s (such as xx.x.xxx.x/api/Controller/Action).

Comment: @christok Yes, apparently if IIS is installed after .NET then you have to go back in to server roles/features and enable .NET 4.6

Comment: Question .Net is installed as well as IIS in roles/features do I need to reinstall it ?

Comment: @MicahArmantrout Shouldn't have to. Go back to the roles/features and find .Net and see if 4.6 is checked/enabled

Comment: it is enabled and IIS is installed but I am still getting this error

Comment: I did notice that my application is for 4.5 and not 4.6 so maybe I need to install 4.5

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using IIS 10 and .NET 4.6

1. Add roles and Features
2. Open up child nodes for WEB Server IIS
3. Under Web Server, open nodes for Application Development
4. Select ".NET Extensibility 4.6", "ASP.NET 4.6"

These resolves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows 10 I was able to resolve this via:

1. Control Panel > Programs & Features > Turn Windows features on or off
2. Removing .NET Framework 4.7 Advanced Services > ASP.NET 4.7
3. Adding it back

Answer (score 0):

for anyone else that runs into this I installed ASP.net 4.6 on Server 2016 in add remove roles and this resolved my issue.